# После установки Windows 11 и переустановки Android studio мое рабочее приложение выдает кучу ошибок

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk

Ниже Model.java активити, которая "ругается" на Method does not override or implemented a method from a supertype (первый оверрайд после объявления переменных), `Cannot find symbol methon on onCreate(Bundle),SetContentViev(int), findviewbyid,getApplicationContext` и так далее. Так же DatabaseHelper подчеркивается красным в 3х последних импортах

```
public class Detail {


    ListView ListView;
    EditText EditText;
    TextView TextView;
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Cursor c;
    SimpleCursorAdapter CAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detail);
        ListView = findViewById(R.id.List);
        EditText = findViewById(R.id.EditText);
        TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        databaseHelper.create_db();


    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        try {

            String comp = getIntent().getStringExtra("comp");
            String model = getIntent().getStringExtra("model");
            String detail = getIntent().getStringExtra("detail");

                if (detail == null || detail == "Нет " || detail == "Нет" || detail == "нет" || detail == "нет ")
            {
                TextView.setText("Деталировки отсутствуют");
            }
            TextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + detail + "\">Деталировки</a> "));
            TextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());



            db = databaseHelper.open();
            c = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE + " where comp='"+comp+"' and model='"+model+"' group by whatis", null);
            String[] headers = new String[]{COLUMN_WHATIS};
            CAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    c, headers, new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2}, 0);


            if (!EditText.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                CAdapter.getFilter().filter(EditText.getText().toString());

            ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent( Detail.this, Info.class);
                        Cursor t = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM kerInfo where _id='"+id+"'", null);
                        t.moveToFirst();
                        intent.putExtra("comp", comp);
                        intent.putExtra("model", model);

                        intent.putExtra("vc", t.getString(t.getColumnIndex("vc")));
                        intent.putExtra("vck", t.getString(t.getColumnIndex("vck")));
                        intent.putExtra("note", t.getString(t.getColumnIndex("note")));
                        intent.putExtra("headof", t.getString(t.getColumnIndex("headof")));
                        startActivity(intent);
                    };

            });

            EditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                }

                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                }

                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                    CAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
                }
            });
            CAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
                @Override
                public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {

                    if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                        return db.rawQuery("select  * from " + TABLE + " group by " + COLUMN_WHATIS, null);
                    } else {
                        return db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE + " where " +
                                COLUMN_COMP + " like ? group by " + COLUMN_WHATIS, new String[]{"%" + constraint.toString() + "%"});
                    }
                }
            });
            ListView.setAdapter(CAdapter);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Закрываем подключение и курсор
        db.close();
        c.close();
    }
}
```

DatabaseHelper.java класс

```
package com.example.crosstable;

import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_PATH; // полный путь к базе данных
    private static String DB_NAME = "info.db";
    private static final int SCHEMA = 1; // версия базы данных
    static final String TABLE = "kerInfo"; // название таблицы в бд
    // названия столбцов
    static final String COLUMN_COMP = "comp";
    static final String COLUMN_MODEL = "model";
    static final String COLUMN_WHATIS = "whatis";
    static final String COLUMN_DETAIL = "detail";
    static final String COLUMN_PROCESS = "process";
    static final String COLUMN_VC = "vc";
    static final String COLUMN_VCK = "vck";
    static final String COLUMN_HEADOF = "headof";
    static final String _id = "_id";
    private Context myContext;

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, SCHEMA);
        this.myContext=context;
        DB_PATH =context.getFilesDir().getPath() + DB_NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,  int newVersion) {
    }

    void create_db(){
        InputStream myInput = null;
        OutputStream myOutput = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(DB_PATH);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                this.getReadableDatabase();
                //получаем локальную бд как поток
                myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
                // Путь к новой бд
                String outFileName = DB_PATH;

                // Открываем пустую бд
                myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

                // побайтово копируем данные
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }

                myOutput.flush();
                myOutput.close();
                myInput.close();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            Log.d("DatabaseHelper", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public SQLiteDatabase open()throws SQLException {

        return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }
}
```

Comment: если у вас это активность то возле объявления класса по логике должно быть типа такого хотя бы `extends AppCompatActivity` и тогда методы станут доступными

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Не подскажете, почему 
Import com.example.crosstable.DatabaseHelper.table; 
Где, DatabaseHelper- класс, table - static final String (название БД)

Comment: мне кажется стоит убрать table и должно помочь

Comment: Это одна из переменных ,которая используется в моей программе. Добавил Код ДБХелпера в вопрос

Comment: Оно используется в sql запросах

Comment: попробуйте убрать вообще импорт, и студия предложит вам заимпортировать так как нужно, просто мне кажется что не нужно указывать имя таблицы при импорте) но я могу ошибаться)

Comment: Уже пробовал удалить, но это не помогает

Comment: так а если импорт удалить, то оно просто подчеркивает красным присваивание значения, и все? ничего не предлагает ?

Comment: попробуй после запуска студии не открывать своё приложение, а импортировать его. Можно попробовать предварительно очистить проект и очистить кеш.

Comment: Не понял в чем была проблема,но переименовал Эл-ты в классе ДбХелпер и тогда импорты начали подчеркиваться